# Multiple equals in variable definition

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript multiple assignment statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679925/javascript-multiple-assignment-statement)

I was wondering what this does. I have tried to search for it, but I can't find out.

```
var config = $.cookie = function (key, value, options) {};
```

I am referring to the multiple equals in the above line. What is it good for? What does it mean? I have never seen that before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are assigning to the variable `config` and the property `cookie` of `$` the anonymous function.

Comment: So really just defining both `config` and `$.cookie` with the same definition?

Comment: Hm... okay. Hoped for something else, not the obvious... :-) Thanks anyway... :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is the same thing:

```
var func = function(key,value,options) {
    return 'test value';
};
config = func;
$.cookie = func;

console.log(config()); // will output 'test value'
console.log($.cookie()); // will also output 'test value'
```

You are assigning a anonymous function to the `config` variable and the `cookie` property of `$`.